# Rename Row-Key In Hbase

Tags: hbase, hdfs

I have a table customer in production, Now I want to rename the rowkey from 'timestamp' to 'SSN timestamp'. How can i do the same? Is there any alter command for changing the existing row keys or is there any other way to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hbase data saved in hdfs. Since hdfs blocks cannot be updated, you cannot update cells in hbase. Update is one delete and one new insert. You can write a map reduce to scan, delete and insert all rows. After that, do a major compaction to clean marked rows for delete.

Comment: I have read in an article that alter command can be used for that. This created the confusion. So do you mean to say that if I want to edit my row key then I have to create a new table and then copy the old table values with the new row-key.

Comment: You dont need to create new table. If your data is small create a new table and load the data again. Timestamp is a bad choice for rowkey because of hotspotting.

Comment: What article are you talking about? Can you paste a link? Thanks.

Comment: @ozhang - Sorry for commenting on an old thread but I didn't follow why Timestamp would be a bad choice for row keys. When data is sorted by timestamps won't be faster to read since the reads would be reading data for an hour, day or a week and in that case records for an given hour would be colocated. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @AndyDufresne probably too late, but might help someone else later, see this explanation: https://sematext.com/blog/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/